# Is there a formula to remove a link or make a cell blank when a checkbox is selected?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Example:
I have a checkbox in C3 that when checked it has condtional formatting that changes the color of the text for that row.
In cell M3 I have a formula for a hyperlink: `=hyperlink("gid=1860403036&range=A67", "Click Here For Checklist")`
Right now when I click the checkbox it changes the color of the entire row including the link.

How can I make the checkbox remove the link and make that cell blank while keeping the rest of the row changed from the conditional formatting?

Is there a formula I can just insert into the hyperlink cell to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a mock-up sheet as well? @EricR

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tiP0WmM3VxImcnfON9w_oWnyDBVqG9LBY-r67anrA48/edit?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's never a sure thing trying to make suggestions without seeing the actual sheet and data. But you can try this in M3:

```
=IF(C3<>TRUE,,hyperlink("gid=1860403036&range=A67", "Click Here For Checklist"))
```

**ADDENDUM** (based on further comments):

You didn't have your links set up like I showed above.

I've added two new sheets (`Erik Help` and `Erik Help 2`).

If your Sheet2 lists are really set up consecutively as they are in your sample spreadsheet, refer to `Erik Help 2` where the *single array formula* in `M3` will produce all results for `M3:M7`.

If your Sheet2 lists are *not* really set up consecutively as they are in your sample spreadsheet, you may need to enter individual formulas, as illustrated in the five separate formulas found in `'Erik Help'!M3:M7`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately that did not work. It made the cell blank even with the checkmark unchecked. I'm not even sure if it is possible. Basically I would like the cell to have "Click Here For Checklist" hyperlink when the checkmark is unchecked and if the checkmark is checked then the cell would be blank.

Comment: I know without a link it is just `=if(C3=TRUE,,"Click Here For Checklist")`. I am just not sure how to add the link when there is something in the cell

Comment: In the interest of efficiency, I can only suggest that you share a link to a copy of the sheet, being sure to set the link's permissions at creation to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor." Otherwise, it's just a guessing game. I need to see the issue myself in context to offer more than I have.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tiP0WmM3VxImcnfON9w_oWnyDBVqG9LBY-r67anrA48/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: The links in Col M of your linked spreadsheet are currently invalid ranges. Make sure those are valid and then check back here to alert me.

Comment: Oops sorry about that. Fixed. Thanks

Comment: See ADDENDUM to my original post and the added sheets/formulas referenced there.

Comment: Hi Erik, thank you very much for your help. It is very close. It is just opposite of what I was looking for. I need it to show the link Click her for Checklist when there is no checkmark and hide when there is a checkmark. Not sure if that if possible or not. The formula you have on Erik Help tab looks like what I need but just reversed as far what the checkmark does. Sorry for my lack of knowledge. I am not good with programming.

Comment: Check your sheet again. It was just a matter of changing <> (i.e., "does not equal") to = (i.e., is equal to").

Comment: Your awesome. Thank you so much that is exactly what I wanted. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad we got it sorted out.